# How can i get the value of multiple anchors in javascript which are generated from php and send the value to another Php page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Here is how my anchors are displayed on the web. I need to get the value of the anchor and send it to another PHP file, so i would use the value of the anchor in my SQL query to give the condition to display all the productId associated with the value of the anchor**

```
   <?php
    include"validations/connection.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * from category ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(categoryName)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        echo'   
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
        ';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $id = $row['categoryId'];
            $sqltwo = "SELECT COUNT(productId) AS num FROM products WHERE categoryId = '$id'";
            $resultwo = $conn->query($sqltwo);
            
            while($rowtwo = $resultwo->fetch_assoc()){
                echo'
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <button value="'.$row['categoryId'].'" class="link-show">'.$row['categoryName'].'</button> <span class="badge badge-danger ml-1">'.$rowtwo['num'].'</span>
                    </li>
                ';
            }
        }
        echo'
            </ul><hr>
        </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

**And here is my JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var id = document.querySelectorAll('.link-show').value;
    document.querySelectorAll('.link-show').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET','validations/retrievebycategory.php?id='+id, true);

            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send();
        })
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Use $_GET["id"] in the PHP to retrieve the category ID after the link is clicked

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i would have an issue of being redirected to that PHP file, but i want to use javascript to prevent the anchor to redirect me, so I'd send the anchor's value using AJAX, can you help me with this?

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. I suggest using a button instead of an anchor, with the category ID as a data attribute or the value of the button. Then there is no question of it redirecting... you can just handle the click event of the button and run the Ajax call. (Of course if you still want it to look like an anchor you can do that with CSS quite easily).

Comment: Thanks, Let me try it,I think that would help.

Comment: I'm facing another issue, the values sent to the PHP file are all returning the same value, ( the value of the first displayed button") , Can you help me deal with that?@ADyson

Comment: First you'll need to edit the question to show the latest version of your code, then I might be able to help. No-one can fix code they cannot see :-)

Comment: I've edited the codes.@ADyson

Comment: `getElementById` only selects one element (which should be obvious since an ID must, by definition, be unique...or you can read the manual). You need to give your buttons a class instead, then select them by the class (using querySelectorAll for example) and then add the event listener to each one. You also need to get the value _inside_ `myFunction` otherwise it won't change when the button is clicked. Use `this.value` to get the value of the button which triggered the click (because that's what `this` always represents inside an event handler callback).

Comment: Hey again, The example you gave me yesterday didn't work, I'm still having the same issue. Maybe you can help me if you have another approach?@ADyson

Comment: It should work. Update the question to show how you've tried to implement my last comment

Comment: I've tried to also loop the elements with the class ( link-show ) since they are multiple, The problem I'm facing now is that, console.log which should be returning an actual value (e.g: 10), rather returns "undefined" as the return value. @ADyson

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    // Remove this, it's querying all links
    // var id = document.querySelectorAll('.link-show').value;
    document.querySelectorAll('.link-show').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            
            // In the event handler, "this" is set to event.currentTarget (the button, in this case).
            // Equivalent formulations:
            // let id = event.currentTarget.value; // (from event, standard behavior, equivalent to "this")
            // let id = event.target.value // (from event's initial target, equivalent in most cases, except if the "click" is generated by a nested element; generally unsafe to use unless the intent is clear)
            // let id = item.value; // (from closure)
            let id = this.value;
            
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET','validations/retrievebycategory.php?id='+id, true);

            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send();
        })
    })
```

See modifications and explanations in the code

Comment: It's returning an error of redeclaration of the variable, since I've declared it already.@Dinu

Comment: Response updated to make it clearer, check comments in the code

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Anyway by using let id = this.value; i was getting "undefined", so i used => let id = item.value; and it worked, Thanks again.@Dinu

Comment: Also, can you explain to me what just happened a little? What did we correct?

Comment: Well, I thought the comments were self-explanatory; here's how you should think as a programmer:

1) Formulate your task in english language:
"When a button is clicked, submit an AJAX request to an URL that depends on the clicked element's value"
Once you've done this, the rest follows:

2) "the clicked element" does not make sense until an element is clicked. So writing ```js var id = document.querySelectorAll('.link-show').value;``` does not make sense. Anything that you might write outside the event handler is senseless. "the clicked element" makes sense only inside the click handler.

Comment: 3) Inside the event handler, transpose "the clicked element's value": in JS, "The clicked element" may mean 2 things: A) The element that is actually clicked ```event.target``` or B) the event the click handler is attached to ```event.currentTarget```. Usually you want to use ```event.currentTarget```, that's why in DOM event handlers, ```this``` is already bound to ```event.currentTarget``` for convenience. So confidently use ```this``` for "the clicked element" and ```.value``` as "'s value". Done.

Comment: Instead of 3), you may opt for 3.2): since you use `.forEach`, you are actually attaching a different handler (closure) to every element. As long as you are doing this (quite unproductive, I might add, but you are doing it) then you may access the `item` variable in the closure directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, Would you mind telling me a more effective way to the it, since what i did is not enough productive. That would help me do my other project in a more effective way! Thanks in advance.@Dinu

Comment: The most effective way I know how is taking the time to read a few good books in the field,

Comment: Would be thankful if you recommend me some! @Dinu